# Execute interactive CLI appilcation from C/C++

Tags: java, c++, c

Java has support for [java.lang.Process](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html). This can be used with [java.lang.ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) or [Runtime.exec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String[],%20java.io.File)). With object of [java.lang.Process](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html). I can interactive with underlying application by reading output stream/error stream and writing to output stream.

Is there any way/library to do similar thing in either c or c++?

I try [popen](https://linux.die.net/man/3/popen), but it is unidirectional, i.e. either I can write or read, can't do both.

Any suggestions are welcome. If there is not solution but have some work around, it also welcome.

Update: I am looking solution for Linux Platform.

Comment: Please try to avoid terms like "C/C++". There's no such language as "C/C++", only the *very different* languages C and C++. Pick *one* language you want help with, and stick with that.

Comment: On the other hand, neither C nor C++ have standard capabilities to run external programs, it's all platform dependent. And since you don't specify target platform this is to broad.

Comment: There's no native cross platform call, Windows has `CreateProcess` not sure about *nix. Though I'm sure you could find an extendable cross platform wrapper via Google.

Comment: Given your link I suppose you will be using linux, so look into the [system](https://linux.die.net/man/3/system) or [exec](https://linux.die.net/man/3/exec) depending on what you want to do, that might come in handy and please, dont (c/c++), it hurts

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude. Point well taken. Updated question.

Answer (score 3):

There is no cross-platform way to launch a new process from either C or C++.  Every platform will have its own interface to do so, assuming it has a concept of processes.

The two interfaces you're most likely to come across are the Windows [`CreateProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) and the POSIX [`fork`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html)/[`exec`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html).

Since you mentioned reading/writing the subprocess's output/input, you'll also need to use the platform's pipe functions: [`CreatePipe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/namedpipeapi/nf-namedpipeapi-createpipe) on Windows or [`pipe`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) on POSIX-compliant platforms.

---

There are cross-platform wrappers for all of that, such as [Boost Process](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/process.html).  None are included with the standard library though, so you'll have to build/install them as you would any other third-party library.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use Managed C++ and .NET, you can use System.Diagnostics.Process, which does the same thing as with `java.lang.Process`.

[Input Redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardinput?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.5.2#System_Diagnostics_ProcessStartInfo_RedirectStandardInput)

[Output Redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.5.2#System_Diagnostics_ProcessStartInfo_RedirectStandardOutput)

The caveat is that you need to build your binary as a C++/CLI project, and have .NET as a dependency. You can get around this by putting the managed code in a separate utility library.